# How come WW3 doesn't happen in the Stein's Gate worldline?

Tags: steins-gate

Since Kurisu is alive, and even though her paper was burned, she would republish it given how seriously her father took it, How come WW3 doesn't happen in the Stein's Gate worldline?

Answer (score 3):

It can be assumed Kurisu would never touch that theory again. Even if she did, it would never end up being used for evil. Otherwise, it would not be Steins Gate and Suzuha would time-travel from the future.

From what we've seen in the *Steins;Gate* visual novel and some drama CDs:

> Time travel can exist in any world line and it doesn't necessarily end up with a dystopia or a world war.

Another perspective for this is the attractor fields. AFs are groups of world lines that converge to the same future. The world lines in the Alpha AF always converge to the SERN dystopia and the Beta to WW3. The world line Steins Gate lies in both Alpha and Beta, making itself its own AF, converging to neither and having its own unknown future. So time travel or not, WW3 should not happen.

This is largely speculation btw.